# Angular path to image in assets on web server

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular. I created a small web application with 2 images. The images are in `myapp/src/assets/img1.jpg`. On my local machine, everything works fine. When I call locasthost:4200 I can see the images, but when I upload the content of the `dist` folder (created with `ng build --prod`) to my web server, the images cannot be found.

my web server:  `abc.host.com/~user1/myapp`

Parts (`myapp`) of the path are cut off. e.g. `abc.host.com/~user1/assets/img1.jpg`.

What `<base href="">` should I use?
What `img src` path to use so that images are shown on web server too?
the following did not work:

```
<img src="/assets/img/img1.jpg" alt="/assets/img/img1.jpg">
<img src="../assets/img/img1.jpg" alt="../assets/img/img1.jpg">
```

I would like to keep everything relative.

SOLUTION:

1. use `<base href="./">` in your index.html
2. `<img src="assets/img/img1.jpg" alt="assets/img/img1.jpg">`

My web server will now get the img from:  `abc.host.com/~user1/myapp/assets/img/img1.jpg`

Comment: try <base href="./">

Comment: ok, that helped!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It all depends on the **base href** you are providing in the **index.html**.
All the images should be kept under **'assets'** folder. And the path for any image in the project must be relative starting from this folder ie.

*src=**"assets/img/img1.jpg"***

As doing this, will remove the difficulty of **file not found**, which will arise in the deployment of the application.

Now, these steps will do the rest.

- ng build --prod **--base-href   /myApp** - this command will add the
  **base-href='/myApp'** to index.html
- Create folder myApp in the server's deployment folder, say in case of tomcat
  make this folder in webapps.
- Copy the contents of dist folder to this myApp folder.
- Run the server.

Application will be accessible at http://localhost:8080/my_app

If you dont want the context 'myApp' for your application, then try doing **base href='./'**

This helped in  my case. Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where your html file exists. According to your data there might be three possibilities:

```
<img src="src/assets/img/img1.jpg" alt="My image"/>
<img src="assets/img/img1.jpg" alt="My image"/>
<img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="My image"/>
```

Comment: The source reference is counting relatively to the html file position. In your case it exists in the same folder as "assets" - in a "src" folder. In case you would want to get any file out of "src" folder, you should use "../[other folder]"

Answer (score 0):

> What `<base href="">` should I use?

Depends on your configuration but in general it should point to your entry point of application. So if your app is available on lets say `example.com` then base href will be `/`

If you app is available under `exampl.com/some/path` then base href should be like `/some/path/`

Comment: hmm but on my local machine the images are under myapp/src/assets/img1.jpg. The "/some/path" will conflict with "myapp/src"

Comment: I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

by passed this by adding two sets of images.

```
<img src="assets/image/tlsTitle16.gif"  onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='ProjectName/assets/image/tlsTitle16.gif';" />
```